# How to call a javascript function using asp.net dropdown list

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to call a `javascript` function when the `dropdown` list is changed.

How can I implement that in `asp.net`?

Comment: asp.net controls eventually rendered as pure html controls. so you shouldnt be having any difficulity accesing them.

Comment: jquery is your best friend for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DDList" onclick="alert(1)"></asp:DropDownList>
```

If you want to get function executed when element clicked, you can use above code to define a function that should be executed 'onclick'.

But it is better to use something like [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener), just search for cross-browser function (for instance, like addListener function [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff728624.aspx)):

```
document.getElementById("<%=DDList.ClientID %>").addEventListener("click", fucntionToExecuteName, false)
```

Remember, than in this case you must take `DDList.ClientID` and use it as id of an element, because it will be different from ID you have set in your aspx code

But if you need some function to be executed when actual value is changed, you should use `onchange` event.

Answer (score 7):

Use `onchange` event to excecute function whenever the dropdown list clicked.

```
<select id="mylist" onchange = "go()">
<option value="value1">value1</option>
<option value="value2">value2</option>
</select>

<script>
  function go()
  {
    var x = document.getElementById("mylist").value;
    console.log(x);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **Jquery** :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#DropDownID").change(function () {
           // Your requirment
     });
});
```

Also it's always better to write it inside the `document.ready`

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this (uses jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dropdownId").change(function(e)) {
             do something...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this script to your mark-up and be sure to also include a script reference to jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $("#yourDropdownId").change(function(){
        //Todo: write your javascript code here.
 });
});
```

Make sure that the control with "yourDropdownId" as ID has the property: "ClientIDMode" set to static or the "all-knowing" ASP.NET engine will auto-generate an element name for the resulting html with parent element names appended to the control by default.

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select[name$=DrpGoingTo]').change(function () {
       //Code here
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `onchange` event and call it from itself:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropdownList" runat="server" onchange="javascript:MyFunction();" >
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList" runat="server" onchange="javascript:OptionHide();" ></asp:DropDownList>